# Несъедобен - слитно или раздельно?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

На вкус абсолютно несъедобен. Считаю, что несъедобен - это краткое прилагательное и с не пишется слитно, так как наречие "абсолютно" усиливает утверждение (то есть вреден). Правильно?

Comment: @Верьясова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Даже если бы не было этого "абсолютно" — все равно лучше писать слитно. *Он несъедобен*. Иногда трудно подобрать синоним без НЕ, но очевидно, что здесь утверждается отрицательный признак, а не отрицается положительный.

Answer (score 1):

> Правильно?

Правильно.

**P.S.**

Только не обязательно вреден. Скорее, *невкусен.*